# cakephp saveAll with no primary key?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, associations

Okei, so how do I go about to tell cake that there is NO ID primary key when saving?

```
associates:
- id (primary key)
- name

associate_tests
- associate_id
- name

model Associate
hasmany AssociateTest

model Assciate_test
belongTo Associate

Cake spit out an error when saveAll;
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'AssociateTest.id' in 'field list'
```

So how to tell cake that ID does not exist? and there is NO unique identifier in that table.

Thanks for suggestions, I am stuck on this.

-Tom

**EDIT; Reason I am looking at a setup like this:**

- IF is save example; 1 screen, with 5 options.
  screen_id = 1 + screenOption = 1 -5

Now, If I edit the screen, and save it again. Screen id = 1, screenOption = 6-10

If I create 1000 screens, and have 5 options on each screen. Every time I save or edit a screen, ALL options will be assigned new ID. This is bacause of jquery add/remove options in view, and I delete ALL the options before saving them in controller because of this. EG: Options will get new ids on every save (resulting in wiiiide id primary_keys, that will never be used for anything).

As ID will never be used, I do not need it. Do you have any other suggestion on a better way to create my table associate_tests ?

Like; ID int(1000), int char(36) ? or something else?

Comment: Wow, ok there's a way to do this - sort of - and it's pretty intense because you're overriding Cake magic. Breaking Cake's conventions is such a catastrophic pain that you might reconsider using Cake. Before I dig into it, how did you manage to load the model schema and acquire a primary key 'id' if the field does not exist? The field for sure does not exist on that table and no reasonable way of adding it?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late reply. I am following your reasoning. ID does not exist, but is possible to add. The reason I want to do this, is because the ID field (lets say int(10), will be incremented on every save. Example; Screen => 5 options, id 1-5. If I now edit and save my edits, the 5 options will now have id 6-10. If example 1000screen, each 5 options. you see, ID will be MIGHTY big in a short time. I loaded with primary key; screen_id in model, just for testing.

Comment: Why will it be incremented on every save? Cake's default magic save() method is an upsert - it checks for the existence of a record by id and generates an UPDATE statement if it finds it.

Comment: The reason was due to jquery and add/remove ajax of form data on add/edit. I have re-written my jquery now, and it is working fine with saveAll. Thanks anyway :p Wanted to use Composite primary_keys, but I found that cake does not support it.

Comment: You can manipulate primary keys to that effect in Cake, but doing so is kind of obscure. Congrats on the fix. :)